if a product is launched and we want the launched year out of product sell in sql
+-------------+-------+
| Column Name | Type  |
+-------------+-------+
| sale_id     | int   |
| product_id  | int   |
| year        | int   |
| quantity    | int   |
| price       | int   |
+-------------+-------+


(sale_id, year) is a composite primary key of this table.
product_id is a foreign key (reference column) to Product table.
Each row of this table shows a sale on the product product_id in a certain year.
Note: price is per unit.

Table: Product
+--------------+---------+
| Column Name  | Type    |
+--------------+---------+
| product_id   | int     |
| product_name | varchar |
+--------------+---------+


product_id is the primary key (column with unique values) of this table.
Each row of this table indicates the product name of each product.

GOAL:

Write a solution to select the product id, year, quantity, and price for the first year of every product sold.

Return the resulting table in any order.

The result format is in the following example.
[Missing...]



"The result format is in the following example" is absent

What RDBMS and version.  There's a few ways this can be accomplished

The Product table is not needed for your goal. You would only need it if the result should have the product name in addition to the ID.

Seems like a question from school. What have you done to solve the problem ? Where is the errors or the problems you enconter ?

Also, what happens if there are multiple times a product was sold in the same (earliest) year?  would the record with the lower Sale_ID be needed?
